# Making Class thread safe

Tags: java, android, multithreading, thread-safety

This code is generated for saving event history in my app as I need to provide some code as :

```
public class LogDataBase {
    public LogDataBase(Context context) {
        try {
            this.context = context;
            String logPath = context.getFilesDir() + logStoragePath;
            file = new File(logPath);
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        Errors += ("\n" + e.getMessage());
        }
    } 
    public void addItem(String log) {
        try {
            dbWriter = new FileWriter(file, true);
            //appand String log to file
            ....
    }
   public ArrayList<String> getArrayList() { 
     //get all Logs as arraylist
    }
}
```

The main question is how to develop app that is thread-safe? As apps may use services and multiprocessing ,multi-threading should ensure that codes and classes is safe.

Please provide some Comprehensive explanation for this important topic(not only saying `Synchronization , Lock,...`) 
hope to be useful for others
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no generic answer on how to make it thread save. Depends on what must not happen concurrently in your class. E.g. the `ArrayList` should probably not be read / modified while you add an item. And if you return a reference to your internal list that would mean that clients calling `getArrayList()` would need to participate in the synchronization

Comment: @zapl I agree with you ,there is no generic answer but maybe exist generic helpful guidance

Comment: That's getting very broad for here. You're better off reading a book like [Java Concurrency in Practice](http://jcip.net/) or watch some videos like [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V2jFpFGAwcU)

Answer (score 1):

synchronization is one of the easiest ways to guarantee a part of code is thread safe. But it will slow down you application because of blocking caused by it. So the best way I suggest is to use producer consumer implementation. So the steps for that is as following

- **Producer**
- you add the item to be logged into a queue. Adding to the queue should be synchronized
- then notify all the threads block on that queue.
- **Consumer**
- A separate thread which consumes the queue when data is available. Reading queue is the only thing needs to be synchronized.
- If there are no items to process in the queue you wait until someone notifies

In this way you can minimize the blocking and guarantee a thread safe way to handle some tasks.

Comment: one of the best answer thanks

Comment: You can use a [BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) to handle blocking and synchronization in the most efficient and simple way.